# When I choose a scale colour, am I a more "pure" breed of Dragonborn?

Tags: dnd-5e, dragonborn

Are the physical features of a Dragon species also the same in Dragonborn and Half-dragon species? Because (obviously, apart from colour) the description of a Dragonborn suggest that they are somewhat "Mongrel" in their evolution:

> First generation dragonborn more strongly resembled their ancestors, especially in terms of scale colour, but generations of interbreeding have created a more unified appearance

This would suggest that because I have chosen a scale colour (other than perhaps brass, bronze, scarlet, rust, gold, or copper-green; which are suggested to be the more "common" scale colours), that my resemblance is in fact closer to the Dragon I came from.

For Half-Dragons however, because they are direct descendants of Dragons themselves; it suggests that their appearance is in fact closer to their descendants:

> A dragon's magical nature allows it to breed with virtually any species. This sort of conception usually happens when a dragon has been polymorphed or had its form changed in some way.

So is it true that if I choose a scale colour when creating my Dragonborn character, that my appearance is similar to the same species of Dragon?

Comment: This is a question for your DM; there is no answer to this question generally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The first dragonborn had scales of vibrant hues matching
>   the colors of their dragon kin, but generations of
>   interbreeding have created a more uniform appearance.
>   Their small, fine scales are usually brass or bronze
>   in color, sometimes ranging to scarlet, rust, gold, or
>   copper-green.
>
> The blood of a particular type of dragon runs
>   very strong through some dragonborn clans. These
>   dragonborn often boast scales that more closely match
>   those of their dragon ancestor—bright red, green, blue,
>   or white, lustrous black, or gleaming metallic gold,
>   silver, brass, copper, or bronze.
>
> **Breath Weapon.** You can use your action to exhale
>   destructive energy. Your draconic ancestry determines
>   the size, shape, and damage type of the exhalation.
>
> When you use your breath weapon, each creature in
>   the area of the exhalation must make a saving throw,
>   the type of which is determined by your draconic
>   ancestry.

That's what it says; everything else is up to you.

> This would suggest that because I have chosen a scale colour ..., that my resemblance is in fact closer to the Dragon I came from.

Well, I don't read that myself but if that's how you want to describe your character, go for your life.

What it *says* is that *some* clans have strong tendencies towards a particular type of dragon and they *often* have scales that match that dragon; this suggests that *most* clans don't and, even in ones that do, *some* individuals don't have those features. Just like *some* groups of humans have similar features but *some* individuals in those groups don't share these features.

There is also no suggestion that this is anyway linked to the Dragonborn's breath weapon. There is no reason that a Dragonborn with red scales can't have a silver dragon's breath weapon; genetics sometimes throws up a redhead amongst a brunette family.

Comment: Your last paragraph seems to conflict with the PHB p. 34: "You have draconic ancestry. Choose one type of dragon from the Draconic Ancestry table. Your breath weapon and damage resistance are determined by the dragon type, as shown in the table."  Are you saying scale color and type of dragon aren't the same thing?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I'm saying there's no reason they have to be. They can be if you want.

Answer (score -6):

According to the description on the [Forgotten Realms wikia](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Dragonborn), dragon born colors do not match their breath. Not only that, some dragonborn, probably because of the mix between individuals over time, can breath more than one type of dragon breath (and a few can even grow wings). That re-enforces the fact that the color and the breath are not one to one related. It can, of course, happen that you are red and breath fire. It probably does not make you purer though since all dragonborns probably have had about the same number of generations and mixing over time.

The link actually describes the concept of clan and family. As you will see what is important to dragonborns is the clan and thus mixing between individuals will definitely happen frequently.

Comment: *"This article is about a 4th Edition race."*

Comment: That's where the Dragonborn are from. They did not magically appear in 5e just like that... I don't foresee the authors to change the history of the dragonborn in each version.

Comment: Dragonborn first appeared in 3e's Races of the Dragon, not in 4e.

Comment: 5e PHB p. 34: "You have draconic ancestry.
Choose one type of dragon from the Draconic Ancestry
table. **Your breath weapon and damage resistance are
determined by the dragon type**, as shown in the [table](http://www.nexttools.us/character-races/dragonborn)."